# Is it possible to require generic type arguments on a Dart class?

Tags: dart, flutter

A common question, specifically since Dart 2, is if it is possible to *require* some or all generic type arguments on some or all types - for example `List<int>` instead of `List` or `MyType<Foo>` instead of `MyType`.

It's not always clear what the *intention* is though - i.e. is this a matter of style (you/your team likes to see the types), to prevent bugs (omitting type arguments seems to cause more bugs for you/your team), or as a matter of contract (your library *expects* a type argument).

For example, on [`dart-misc`](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/misc/jDI3QAR6G_M/6X-wbIMsBgAJ), a user writes:

Basically, if I have this:

> ```
> abstract class Mixin<T> {}
> ```
>
> I don't *have* to specify the type:
>
> ```
> // Works class Cls extends Object with Mixin<int> {} // ...also works
> class Cls extends Object with Mixin {}
> ```
>
> Is there some way to make the second one not allowed?

Answer (score 19):

Strictly speaking, yes, *and* no.

If you want to enforce that type arguments are *always* used in your own projects (instead of relying on type inference or defaults), you can use *optional* [linter rules such as `always_specify_types`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/always_specify_types.html). Do note this rule violates the official Dart style guide's recommendation of [`AVOID redundant type arguments on generic invocations`](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-redundant-type-arguments-on-generic-invocations) in many cases.

If you want to enforce that *generic* type arguments are *always* used *when* the default would be confusing - such as `List` implicitly meaning `List<dynamic>`, no such lint exists *yet* - though we plan on adding this as a *mode* of the analyzer: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33119.

---

Both of the above recommendations will help *yourself*, but if you are creating a library for *others* to use, you might be asking if you can *require* a type argument to use your class. For example, from above:

```
abstract class Mixin<T> {}
abstract class Class extends Object with Mixin {}
```

The first thing you could do is add a default bounds to `T`:

```
// If T is omitted/not inferred, it defaults to num, not dynamic.
abstract class Mixin<T extends num> {}
```

If you want to allow *anything* but want to make it difficult to use your class/mixin when `T` is dynamic you could choose a different default bound, for example `Object`, or even better [I recommend `void`](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-legacy-of-the-void-e7afb5f44df0):

> In practice, I use `void` to mean “anything and I don’t care about the elements”

```
abstract class Mixin<T extends void> {
  T value;
}

class Class extends Mixin {}

void main() {
  var c = Class();
  // Compile-time error: 'oops' isn't defined for the class 'void'.
  c.value.oops();
}
```

(You could also use `Object` for this purpose)

If this is a class under your control, you could add an *assertion* that prevents the class from being used in a way you don't support or expect. For example:

```
class AlwaysSpecifyType<T> {
  AlwaysSpecifyType() {
    assert(T != dynamic);
  }
}
```

Finally, you could write a custom lint or tool to disallow certain generic type arguments from being omitted, but that is likely the most amount of work, and if any of the previous approaches work for you, I'd strongly recommend those!

Comment: There are so many things missing in Dart. It's dazzling how many times I've searched for something just to find out there isn't any supported way to do it in the language.